# How to query a user's display information in the AccountDisplayInformation from the AccountModel

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Account is my AUTH_USER_MODEL and AccountDisplayInfo consists of all the additional display info of every account. So they can input and submit, and subsequently update their information. These are my codes, but I'm unsure why it isn't working. First of all, I am receiving this error:

`DoesNotExist at /account/5/displayinfo/ AccountDisplayInfo matching query does not exist.`

Secondly, the "update" function isn't working.

models.py

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
 email                  = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
 username               = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)

class AccountDisplayInfo(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    instagram = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, blank=True, null=True) #instagram
```

.html

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}

{{ form.as_p }}


<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm col-lg-5">Update</button>
</div>

</form>
```

views.py

```
def display_information_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
 user_id = kwargs.get("user_id")
 account = Account.objects.get(pk=user_id)
 context = {}
 displayinfo = AccountDisplayInfo.objects.get(account=account)
 if request.POST:
  form = DisplayInformationForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user)
  if form.is_valid():
      info = form.save(commit=False)
      info.account = request.user
      info.save()
      messages.success(request, 'Your profile display information have been updated', extra_tags='editdisplayinfo')
      return redirect("account:view", user_id=account.pk)
  else:
   form = DisplayInformationForm(request.POST, instance=request.user,   
   initial={
     "instagram": displayinfo.instagram,
    }
   )

   context['form'] = form
 else:
  form = DisplayInformationForm(
    initial={
     "instagram": displayinfo.instagram,
    }
   )
  context['form'] = form
 return render(request, "account/displayinfo.html", context)
```

forms.py

```
class DisplayInformationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AccountDisplayInfo
        fields = ('instagram')
```

Also, would be great if you can advise on this::
If I have 2 tables. Table 1 and Table 2. Table 2 has a foreign key to table 1 but table 1 dont have a foreign key to table 2. How can I query table 2's data from table 1? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you've created the `AccountDisplayInfo` enty for your account?

Comment: @SLDem nope I haven't bro. But shouldn't it show as blank for me to fill up if i haven't created it?

Comment: so the first time would be an input, then subsequently it'll be considered update

Comment: ok bro I tried in admin and it works if I had created an entry for that. However, the update doesn't work. The form is registered as valid but the new update that I insert in is not registered

Comment: are you sure your form is valid?

Comment: yes I'm sure bro. Because I inserted a success message after form.save() and it was shown. I got a feeling it might be because of some foreign key issue?

Comment: do you have 2 or more AccountDisplayInfo objects for the same account perhaps?

Comment: nope bro I only have 1. It works when i edit in admin.py but doesnt work when i do it from my website. i have included by html

Comment: check the update in my answer

Comment: this is weird bro. It registers as valid, but the new value isn't updated. The old value will still show. And when I check admin.py it also shows the old value

Comment: its almost as if they were submitting using the pre-existing old values without giving a darn about the updated value @SLDem

Comment: well thats not possible because it does register as valid, did you do all the steps including removing the `save` method from your form class?

Comment: bro i have updated my forms.py^ check the code above :)

Comment: and your view aswell?

Comment: actually I would want to automatically move this discussion to chat but i dont have enough reputation haha..unless you upvote my question for a while :)

Comment: wait let me show you the updated view :) meanwhile you can look at my html :)

Comment: btw my display information entry was created from django admin, if it matters, because i havent learnt how to write signals to make it such that when i create an account object, i will autocreate a accountdisplayinfo object

Comment: can't move you to chat, you need more reputation, I don't know how I can help now, try debugging your view, I will check up later since right now I'm kinda busy

Comment: sure bro, I have just made a signal which generates an entry of AccountDisplayInfo everytime an account is created

Answer (score 0):

By default `.get()` will return a `DoesNotExist` exception if no object matches the query you executed and stop the code from running, so if you want to input it manually on the same page use `filter` instead:

```
displayinfo = AccountDisplayInfo.objects.filter(account=account).first()
```

Then in your template do something like this:

```
{% if displayinfo %}
   ... show display info...
{% else %}
   <p> No info yet </p> <!-- (or show some form) -->
{% endif %}
```

To answer your other question:

You have to use the `related_name` or related models attribute to access the `ForeignKey` data or use the *model name* with the `_set` suffix, for example:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_lenght=10)

class Comment(models.Model):
    body = models.CharField(max_lenght=200)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
```

then you would get the `Post` and its comments:

```
post = Post.objects.get(pk=1)
comments = post.comments.all()
```

if you didn't have the `related_name` attribute in your model field you would do this instead:

```
comments = post.comment_set.all()
```

**UPDATE**

Maybe the issue is in your `Form` class, try removing the `save` method from it and instead do this in your **view**:

```
if request.POST:
    form = DisplayInformationForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user)
    if form.is_valid():
        info = form.save(commit=False)
        info.account = request.user
        messages.success(request, 'Your profile display information have been updated', extra_tags='editdisplayinfo')
        info.save()
        return redirect("account:view", user_id=account.pk)
```

Comment: 2nd answer is very detailed. thank you bro. However for the first question, why is it that even if there was already an entry, the update doesn't work. The form is registered as valid but the new update that I insert in is not registered